# About getting sound waveform in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, waveform

Is it possible to get whole waveform of a mp3 sound in AS3 without the need to pass all the sound with the playhead and how?

Are there any functions that do this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I completely understand your question, but you're probably looking for the `SoundMixer` class, which has a `computeSpectrum()` function that gives you a snapshot of the current sound wave: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundMixer.html#computeSpectrum()

Comment: Yup, I was asking whether I am able to get at once the full waveform of the sound? For example there are sound editing programs where when some sound file opened the whole song is shown as a sound wave in left and right channel. something like this [link]http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/images/audacity-macosx.png

Comment: I'm not sure if you can get the entire sound wave without playing through the sound itself - not my strong point. try searching around for `computeSpectrum()` tutorials

Comment: Ok. Also is it possible to get the whole sound data in raw form and draw it in a graphic?  For example I get byte by byte of the sound and draw it part by part

Comment: You can probably get the entire thing in a ByteArray using the `extract()`: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html#extract(), but you'll have to read in the values yourself.

Comment: thanks, havent used extract() before. Didn had any idea of it.